# CTE Query and DateTime Matching

Tags: sql, datetime, recursion, sql-server

I have two tables (they are defined below and you can use the SQL below to build them)

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ETab')
DROP TABLE ETab;
GO

CREATE TABLE ETab 
    ([MRN] varchar(20), [LSPEC] varchar(2), [ADT] DATETIME, [SDT] DATETIME, [Source] varchar(20), [Enum] varchar(20));
GO

INSERT INTO ETab ([MRN], [LSPEC], [ADT], [SDT], [Source], [Enum]) 
VALUES 
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEBLD04'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-31 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEBLD05'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-30 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEBLD06'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-07-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-07-31 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEBLD07'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-08-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-08-31 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEBLD08'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-09-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-09-30 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEBLD09'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HQ',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEDRG04HM'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-31 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEDRG05HM'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-30 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEDRG06HM'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-07-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-07-31 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEDRG07HM'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-08-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-08-31 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEDRG08HM'),
    ('HOMECARE',    'HM',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-09-01 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-09-30 00:00:00.000', 20),   'PRODPAT',  'HOMEDRG09HM'), 
    ('111824',      'UR',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-09-22 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-09-22 00:00:00.000', 20),   'OP',   'OP1118240003'),
    ('111824',      'NL',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-19 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-19 00:00:00.000', 20),   'OP',   'OP1118240001'),
    ('111824',      'MS',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-30 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-30 00:00:00.000', 20),   'OP',   'OP1118240002'),
    ('111824',      'MS',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-24 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-24 00:00:00.000', 20),   'IP',   'IP1118240001'),
    ('111824',      'MS',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-28 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-28 00:00:00.000', 20),   'IP',   'IP1118240005'),
    ('111824',      'MS',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-27 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-27 00:00:00.000', 20),   'IP',   'IP1118240004'),
    ('111824',      'MS',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-26 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-26 00:00:00.000', 20),   'IP',   'IP1118240003'),
    ('111824',      'MS',       CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-25 00:00:00.000', 20),   CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-25 00:00:00.000', 20),   'IP',   'IP1118240002');
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'UTab')
DROP TABLE UTab;
GO

CREATE TABLE UTab 
    (MRN varchar(20), SIDate DATETIME, LSPEC varchar(2), Source varchar(20), Enum varchar(20), Iteration varchar(20));
GO

INSERT INTO UTab 
    (MRN, SIDate, LSPEC, Source, Enum, Iteration) 
VALUES 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-20 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-20 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-20 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-20 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-20 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-20 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-20 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-17 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HQ', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-01 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-06-26 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-30 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL), 
('HOMECARE', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000', 20), 'HM', 'N', NULL, NULL),
('111824', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-21 00:00:00.000', 20), 'MS', 'IP', NULL, NULL), 
('111824', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-24 00:00:00.000', 20), 'NL', 'OP', NULL, NULL), 
('111824', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-27 00:00:00.000', 20), 'NL', 'OP', NULL, NULL), 
('111824', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-20 00:00:00.000', 20), 'NL', 'OP', NULL, NULL), 
('111824', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-20 00:00:00.000', 20), 'NL', 'OP', NULL, NULL), 
('111824', CONVERT(datetime, '2017-04-20 00:00:00.000', 20), 'NL', 'OP', NULL, NULL);
GO

SELECT * FROM ETab
WHERE Source = 'PRODPAT' AND LSPEC = 'HM' 
GO

SELECT * FROM UTab  
WHERE LSPEC = 'HM';
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '__Tmp')
DROP TABLE __Tmp;
GO
```

I have a C# application in which the user requests certian matching clauses at run-time. Using the information specified by the user, I generate some SQL that is executed and updates `UTab`.

Via the generated SQL, I wish to perform some matching which updates the `[UTab].[Enum]` based on the link field `[MRN]` and whether `[UTab].[SIDate]` lies within `[ETab].[ADT]` and `[ETab].[SDT]` +- some days before or after which are specified by the user. So, the user might specify two commands, the first:

```
MatchCmd:MRN,LSPEC:ETab:UTab:ADT:SDT:SIDate:0:1:'Iteration#1':WHERE [UTab].[Source] = 'OP' AND [UTab].[LSPEC] = [ETab].[LSPEC]
```

> This says, match on `MRN` AND `LSPEC` from source table `ETab`, updating `UTab` where `SIDate > ADT - 0 day(s)` and `SIDate < SDT + 1 day(s)` and where `[UTab].[Source] = 'OP'` - any matches I mark with the "iteration number" `Iteration#1`.

My code generates the following SQL:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [ETab].[Enum] AS Enum, 
           [ETab].[MRN] AS Link, 
           [ETab].[ADT] AS ADT, 
           [ETab].[SDT] AS SDT, 
           [UTab].[SIDate] AS DT, 
           [ETab].[MRN] AS [MRN], 
           [ETab].[LSPEC] AS [LSPEC], 
           [ETab].[Source] AS [Source], 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [UTab].[MRN], [UTab].[LSPEC], [UTab].[SIDate] 
                ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(mi, [UTab].[SIDate], [ETab].[ADT]))) AS Idx, 
           ABS(DATEDIFF(mi, [UTab].[SIDate], [ETab].[ADT])) AS Diff 
    FROM [UTab] 
        LEFT JOIN [ETab] ON [UTab].[MRN] = [ETab].[MRN] 
    WHERE ([UTab].[SIDate] BETWEEN 
        DATEADD(dd, -0, [ETab].[ADT]) AND 
        DATEADD(dd, 1, [ETab].[SDT]) AND [Iteration] IS NULL) 
            AND ETab.Source = 'OP' 
            AND UTab.LSPEC = ETab.LSPEC
)  SELECT * 
   INTO __Tmp 
   FROM cte; 
GO
```

To get all the records that match the criteria (laying within the time window and abiding by custom where clauses). Then I Update the `[UTab].[Enum]` and `[UTab].[Iteration]` via another generated query

```
UPDATE [UTab] 
SET [ENum] = [__Tmp].[ENum], [Iteration] = N'Iteration#1' 
--SELECT __Tmp.ENum, __Tmp.Link, __Tmp.LSPEC, __Tmp.ADT, __Tmp.SDT, __Tmp.DT, __Tmp.Idx 
FROM [UTab] AS up 
    INNER JOIN [__Tmp] 
        ON [up].[MRN] = [__Tmp].[Link] 
WHERE __Tmp.Idx = '1' 
    AND up.SIDate = __Tmp.DT 
    AND up.Source = 'OP' 
    AND up.LSPEC = __Tmp.LSPEC;
```

This seems to work okay, but some questions:

Q1. Is there anything clearly awry with the method/SQL I am using?

Q2. Do I need to add joins for the `up.LSPEC = __Tmp.LSPEC` specification or is the `WHERE` clause enough?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a user mashes some buttons on your application, then in the app you generate the TSQL pass it to SQL Server and then it generates some more TSQL for an update, and then issue that syntax to SQL Server to update records in a table.

The SQL syntax looks fine, I would suggest a slightly different approach.

Rather than generate SQL and pass it to the server, you should evaluate the generated code, I would suspect it is similar every time you generate it. The items that change should be able to be parameterized, and you could store the SQL syntax in a user stored procedure, getting re-use and efficiency / performance gains.

The update statement would also benefit from creating a user stored procedure.

This will also help you with security later on if you find the need. Also later when you want to make changes having the SQL code loosely coupled with your C# code will allow you to skip making change to your C# code, re-compile and re-deploy app code.

If you are not familiar with creating user stored procedures, I would suggest looking for some templates, you'll want to create a header with basic info about the user stored procedure. If you have several database objects you might consider reading about database schema, to make it easier to manage different processes or organizational units within the database, also 'dbo' is boring. Using usp_NameSpace is okay, but don't use Hungarian notation on tables please.

I have also found it helps to keep an excel document up-to-date with application functionality and the `usp_` it calls.

Answer (score 1):

You have an implicit inner join in your left join statement

```
      WHERE     ( UTab.SIDate BETWEEN DATEADD( dd, -0, ETab.ADT ) AND DATEADD( dd, 1, ETab.SDT )
                  AND   Iteration IS NULL)
                AND ETab.Source = 'OP'
                AND UTab.LSPEC = ETab.LSPEC
```

Any time you filter for a value on the right side of a left join (other than `NULL`), you implicitly convert your left join into an inner join.  Most of the time the optimizer will detect this and convert it to an inner join, but not always and it can seriously affect performance if it does not.

Second, your update statement is filtering to Idx=1.

```
SELECT    * INTO __Tmp 
FROM  cte 
WHERE   cte.Idx = 1
```

Did you try filtering the result set before inserting into __Tmp?  Performance may be different (better or worse depending on indexing).

Finally, I would change your UPDATE clause to be:

```
INNER JOIN [__Tmp] 
ON [up].[MRN] = [__Tmp].[Link] 
AND up.SIDate = __Tmp.DT 
AND up.Source = __Tmp.Source
AND up.LSPEC = __Tmp.LSPEC
WHERE __Tmp.Idx = '1'
```

Anytime you are comparing fields from two tables, the comparison should be part of the join condition.

I also changed your up.Source field to join to the __Tmp.Source since you're using the same literal value for each.